# Rails 6 Migration giving strange error after using multiple databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-6, multiple-databases

I'm using Two databases in my project using default rails 6 support.

database.yml:-

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  migrations_paths: "db/migrate/primary"
  encoding: unicode
  min_messages: warning
  username: ########
  password: ########
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host_name: localhost

development:
  primary:
    <<: *default
    database: primary_db
  hrm:
    <<: *default
    database: hrm_db
    migrations_paths: "db/migrate/hrm"
```

Model'l of Secondary database are like:

```
class HRM::ServiceHistory < ApplicationRecord
  connects_to database: { writing: :hrm, reading: :hrm }

  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :designation
.
.
```

Migration file:-

```
class ModifyDesigs < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_column :service_histories, :basic_scale, :integer
    remove_column :employees, :designation_id

    add_column :employees, :current_position_id, :integer

    HRM::ServiceHistory.reset_column_information
    HRM::Employee.reset_column_information
    puts "\n\n=================== #{HRM::Employee.first.name} \n\n"

    HRM::Employee.all.each do |emp|
        emp.service_histories.each do |sh|
            des = sh.designation
            sh.basic_scale = des.basic_scale
            sh.save!
        end
        sh = emp.service_histories.order('appointment_date desc').limit(1).first
        if sh
            emp.current_position = sh
            emp.save!
        end
    end
  end
end
```

All normal DDL statements are running file, even `HRM::Employee.first.name` doesn't raise error but further statements raise errors:

```
== 20200409162158 ModifyDesigs: migrating =====================================
-- add_column(:service_histories, :basic_scale, :integer)    -> 0.0041s
-- add_column(:service_histories, :scale, :integer)    -> 0.0005s
-- add_column(:service_histories, :scale_type, :string, {:limit=>1})    -> 0.0005s
-- remove_column(:employees, :designation_id)    -> 0.0050s
-- add_column(:employees, :current_position_id, :integer)    -> 0.0004s
-- add_index(:employees, :current_position_id)    -> 0.0114s
-- add_foreign_key(:employees, :service_histories, {:column=>:current_position_id})    -> 0.0044s


=================== Employee Name

rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ConnectionBad: connection is closed
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:65:in `exec'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in query'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:64:in `block in query'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:718:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:717:in `block in log'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:708:in `log'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:63:in `query'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:98:in `query_value'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:383:in `release_advisory_lock'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1384:in `ensure in with_advisory_lock'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1385:in `with_advisory_lock'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1229:in `migrate'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1061:in `up'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `migrate'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:238:in `migrate'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:114:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'...


Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: connection is closed
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:65:in `exec'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in query'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'...
.
.
Caused by:
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::ConnectionBad: connection is closed
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:92:in `exec'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:92:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'...
.
.
Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ConnectionBad: connection is closed
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:92:in `exec'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:92:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'...
.
.
Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: connection is closed
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:92:in `exec'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:92:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'...
.
.
Caused by:
NoMethodError: undefined method `basic_scale=' for #<HRM::ServiceHistory:0x000000000f3b7c98>
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activemodel-6.0.2.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:431:in `method_missing'
/var/www/dris/releases/315/db/migrate/hrm/20200409162158_modify_desigs.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in change'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:85:in `each'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:85:in `each'
/var/www/dris/releases/315/db/migrate/hrm/20200409162158_modify_desigs.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in change'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:85:in `each'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:85:in `each'
/var/www/dris/releases/315/db/migrate/hrm/20200409162158_modify_desigs.rb:17:in `block in change'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:269:in `swap_connection_handler'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:176:in `with_handler'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:132:in `connected_to'
/var/www/dris/releases/315/db/migrate/hrm/20200409162158_modify_desigs.rb:15:in `change'..
.
.
```

This is error of just single run. I tried many times, sometimes task hangs on `puts HRM::Employee.first.name` and sometimes error as shown above.Looks like concurrent migrations were running, but they shouldn't. Although last paragraph of error log describes some mistake in my iterations, but `basic_scale=` is defined and I've tested in console. Even this migration is running successfully from rails console.
I've never faced such issue before using **two databases** and before migrating to **Rails 6**.

**Edit: I tried splitting migration at the point of DML statements, and migrations run successfully. If I'm resetting column information in a single migration, it shouldn't cause this issue. It's quite strange why splitting migrations resolves the issue.**

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `basic_scale=' for #<HRM::ServiceHistory:0x000000000f3b7c98> , this part looks important!

Comment: I've already tested this and it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to happen when invoking a model's own connection (like calling `model.save` or `Model.connection.execute`) inside the migration *together* with calling any `ActiveRecord::Migration` methods like `create_table`, etc. It breaks Rails' internal connection handling and causes weird behaviour. I've personally run into `connection closed` errors, but also it wrote to the wrong `schema_information` table.

[Rails team is notified of this bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/41855) and it should be fixed as for Rails 7.1. If you can't upgrade: splitting up your migration into 2 will solve this issue: one for your modifying the database and the other for calling models (`.save` etc) (just like mentioned)

Example:

```
# First modify table
class ModifyTables < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_column :foo, :bar, :string
    drop_column :foo, :baz
  end
end

# THEN modify data
class ModifyData < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def up
    Foo.find_each do |foo|
      foo.update!(bar: "baz")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for referring to the bug report. Looks like my question was too early for the feature even before bug report that's why couldn't find any answer for long.